# Manually escaping URL query string

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I have a URL string

```
https://example.com/search?'=$&(=/&)=!
```

that I'd like to transform into its escaped form

```
https://example.com/search?%28=%2F&%29=%21&%27=%24
```

as reported by `res.request.path_url` using Python.

I've played around with `urllib.parse.quote`/`parse_qs`, but that didn't quite get me there:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote, urlsplit, parse_qs

# reference:
res = requests.get("https://example.com/search", params={"(": "/", ")": "!", "'": "$"})
print(res.request.path_url)

url = "https://example.com/search?'=$&(=/&)=!"
p = urlsplit(url)

path_url = p.path or "/"
if p.query:
    parsed_query = parse_qs(p.query)
    escaped_qs = "&".join(
        f"{quote(key)}={','.join(quote(item) for item in value)}"
        for key, value in parse_qs(p.query).items()
    )
    path_url += f"?{escaped_qs}"

print(path_url)
```

```
/search?%28=%2F&%29=%21&%27=%24
/search?%27=%24&%28=/&%29=%21
```

Perhaps there's an easier way altogether. Any hints?

Comment: Can you explain why `'=$&(=/&)=!` would even make sense as query, as opposed to using something like `search?q=thatStringButProperlyEncoded`? Especially since reading the search query back out would require accessing the value using `'` as key, which is... quite strange.

Comment: It's a valid URL in `requests` (or at least it knows how to deal with it), so I have to deal with it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `quote` with [the `safe` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) set to `=` so it's preserved, e.g.:

```py
from urllib.parse import quote

url = "https://example.com/search?'=$&(=/&)=!"
(_, query) = url.split('?')
safified = [quote(x, safe='=') for x in query.split('&')]
print(safified) # ['%27=%24', '%28=%2F', '%29=%21']
```